# What is the probability that the hash of a hash is the same hash?

Tags: probability, hash-function

Given an $n$-bit uniform cryptographic hash function (128-bit `md5`, 256-bit `sha-256`, etc), what is the probability that the input is the same as the output?

Let the hash of $x$ be denoted by $f(x)$. **What is the probability that $f(x) = x$, where $f$ is an $n$-bit hash function?**

For simplicity, assume that we are using a 128-bit `md5` hashing function. The input is limited to the domain of `00000000000000000000000000000000` to `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (since the domain must be the same as the range otherwise the input cannot possibly be the same as the output). There are $2^{128}$ possible inputs. There are also $2^{128}$ possible outputs. Does this mean that for any given uniform hash function, there is nearly a 100% probability that $f(x) = x$ for a single $x$ in the domain?

Comment: It depends very much on the hashing function.  It would be possible to create a function where the hash of of a hash is never the original hash, and it is possible to create functions where the hash of a hash is always the original hash.  I don't know enough about md5 to be able to answer that specific question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "uniform hash function". The probability that a random permutation of a set of $n$ integers has exactly one fixed point seems highly unlikely to be 100% to me. Perhaps that isn't what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N$ be the number of inputs/outputs (e.g., $N=2^{128}$).
Assuming that hashes are uniformly distributed, $\mathbb{P}(f(x)=x)=1/N$ for any given $x$.

The probability of at least one fixed point (i.e., that one or more input maps to itself) is, under the same assumption as above,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\exists x\colon x=f(x)) & =1-\mathbb{P}(\forall x\colon x\neq f(x))\\
 & =\textstyle{1-\prod_{x}\mathbb{P}(x\neq f(x))}\\
 & =\textstyle{1-\prod_{x}\left(1-\mathbb{P}(x=f(x))\right)}\\
 & =\textstyle{1-(1-1/N)^{N}}.
\end{align*}
This is approximately $1 - 1 / e \approx 0.632$ for $N$ sufficiently large (to see this, take the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$).

Comment: "what the probability of a "collision" is (i.e., that one or more inputs map to themselves)": n.b.,  the usual definition of "collision" is when a hash algorithm produces the same hash value for two different input values.

Comment: Your derivation of $1 - 1/e$ looks correct to me, but why is this different that the "common sense" of $2^{N} \times \frac{1}{2^{N}} = 1$? (each of the $2^{N}$ inputs has a $\frac{1}{2^{N}}$ probability of the output being the same as the input)

Comment: @hioqobipb: I changed "collision" to "fixed point".

Comment: @hioqobipb: By the same "common sense", if I have a trial with a 50% chance of success and run 4 trials, I have a 200% (?) chance of observing at least one success.

Comment: @hioqobipb in general $P(A\text{ or }B)=P(A)+P(B)$ only if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, that is, if $P(A\text{ and }B)=0$. Otherwise $P(A\text{ or }B)$ will be smaller than the sum.

Comment: @Carmeister I don't understand. Can you spell out what $A$ and $B$ are in your statement? Is $A = x$ and $B = f(x)$? If so, then what does $P(A\text{ or }B)$ represent?

Comment: A and B are "events" (i.e., things which can be assigned a probability). Intuitively, an event could be "I will win the lottery" or "it will be sunny tomorrow".

Comment: @hioqobipb You are calculating the average number of collisions/fixed points/successes, not the probability there is at least 1.

Comment: @Lucenaposition: I disagree. Let $F_i$ be the indicator random variable associated to the collision $f(x_i) = x_i$. Then the average number of collisions under the assumptions in my answer is just $$\mathbb{E}[F_{1}+\cdots+F_{N}]=N\mathbb{E}F_{1}=N\frac{1}{N}=1.$$

Comment: That is my point precisely.

Comment: I apologize, I mistakenly thought your comment was directed at me.

Comment: The assumption missing an important word _uniformly randomly_ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/19493/18298

Comment: @kelalaka: "Assuming that hashes are uniformly distributed"

Comment: Uniformly distributed doesn't cover all possible hash functions family. Even we don't know SHA-1, SHA256, etc. are uniformly distributed. The premise is false. If you look at carefully, the true calculation comes from selecting one uniformly randomly from all possible hashes...